# Can you do a create or update item in a map array in firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a user populated document with a number of arrays containing maps. It seems that `arrayUnion()` only works on existing arrays so the following won't work unless there's already an array there:

```
docRef.update({
  [dynamicFieldName]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(whateverUpdate)
})
```

Comment: 1) `FieldValue.arrayUnion` will create an array if the field doesn't exist. But if the field already exists and is **not** an array using `FieldValue.arrayUnion` won't change the field to an array. 2) Does your `docRef` point to an existing document? Calling `docRef.update()` will only update existing documents, it won't create a new one if the document doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, ok thanks for clarifying. The document may or may not exist, so i suppose i need to change this to a `set()` with merging on?

Comment: Yup, in that case you'll indeed need to `set(..., { merge: true })` as shown in the second snippet here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know if a list field exists or not, you will have to read the document, check if the array field exists, then update the document with the new array value.

If you need this operation to be atomic, then you should use a transaction. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions